# How to pass an API response from a child component to another nested component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component `MockTable`in which I'm fetching an API response and storing into a variable `data`. I want to use the data in another component `UsecasePane`. May I know the correct way to pass data to `UsecasePane`?

- `MockTable` is the child component of `MainContent`.
- `AddMock` is the child component of `MainContent`.

=> MainContent.js

```
const MainContent = () => {
  return (
    <div >
      <CustomerTable />
      <AddMock />
      <MockTable />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainContent;
```

Now `TabContent` is the child of `AddMock`

=> AddMock.js

```
const AddMock = () => {
  return (
    <div className="row">
              <Container className="mockbody">
                <Header as="h3">Hierarchy</Header>
                <TabContent />
              </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddMock;
```

`UsecasePane` is nested inside the `TabContent`.

// TabContent.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Tab } from "semantic-ui-react";
import UsecasePane from "./UsecasePane";

const panes = [
  {
    menuItem: "Usecase",
    render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}>{<UsecasePane />}</Tab.Pane>,
  }
];

const TabContent = () => (
  <Tab menu={{ secondary: true, pointing: true }} panes={panes} />
);

export default TabContent;
```

=> MockTable.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../assets/css/material-dashboard.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { Icon, Dimmer, Loader, Segment } from "semantic-ui-react";

let config = require("../appConfiguration");

const MockTable = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios
      .get(config.App_URL.getAllTest, {
        params: {
          customHostName: "suite",
          type: "routes",
        },
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Error in fetching the data ${error}`);
      });
    let list = [response.data];
    setData(list);
    setLoading(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  
return (
     // rest of the code
)
  
};
export default MockTable;
```

Now I need to pass this data to `UsecasePane` which is nested in another component `TabContent`

Comment: Can you please define the hierarchy of your components?

Comment: @PramodMali : I did some edits in the question

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to pass data to child components.

1. Using props

```
//In Grandparent
<Parent dataToParent={someData}/>

//In Parent 
<Child dataToChild={props.dataToParent}/>

//Using in Child
render(){
   {props.dataToChild}
}
```

2. Render props(skipping a hierarchy)

https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

```
//In Grandparent component
<Parent dataToParent={dataFromParent => (
  <Child>{dataFromParent}</Child>
)}/>
```

3. Storing data in the central state

Context API: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Third-Party Libs:

i.e. Redux https://redux.js.org/

**Edit:**

Thank you for updating the question. By looking at the hierarchy it seems that you are dealing with sibling components. i.e. `MainContent -> MockTable` is where you are fetching the data and `MainContent -> AddMock -> TabContent -> UsecasePane` where you want to display/pass the data. For both of these the immediate common parent is `MainContent`.

If you don't want to use ContextAPI or any other third-party lib. I would suggest to [lift up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) your states to `MainContent` and pass a callback function to `MockTable` and pass state to `MainContent -> AddMock -> TabContent -> UsecasePane`

Consider the following example:

```js
//MainContent.js
const MainContent = () => {
  ...
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  ...
  return (
    <div >
      <CustomerTable />
      <AddMock setData={setData} /> {/*Passing callback function*/}
      <MockTable data={data} /> {/*Passing state*/}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainContent;
```

```js
//AddMock.js
...
const fetchData = async () => {
    // all data fetching logic remains the same.
    let list = [response.data];
    props.setData(list); //Calling callback function to set the state defined in MainContent.js
  };

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
...
```

```
//AddMock.js

const AddMock = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <div className="row">
              <Container className="mockbody">
                <Header as="h3">Hierarchy</Header>
                <TabContent data={data} /> {/*Passing data props*/}
              </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddMock;

//TabContent.js

const TabContent = ({data}) => {
const panes = [
  {
    menuItem: "Usecase",
    render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}>{<UsecasePane data={data} />}</Tab.Pane>,
  }
];
 return(
  <Tab menu={{ secondary: true, pointing: true }} panes={panes} />
 )
}

export default TabContent;
//
```

Here you can see that to pass data, some `prop drilling` is happening, though it's not an anti pattern but would recommend to avoid as much as possible spcially in the functional components as they don't have support for `shouldComponentUpdate()` or `React.PureComponent` otherwise you can use `React.memo` HOC [Read more](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

Of Course React.Context or Third party libs i.e. Redux(Though it'll be overkilled for small applications) are few alternatives to all of these.

Comment: Thanks Pramod for the detailed explanation. Let me try out this. :)

Comment: Hey I thought i'll stick with context API now.. so my doubt is if i encapsulate my component as like  
``<dataProvider> 
      <div>
          <input1 />
     </div>
</dataProvider>
``
Will the nested components  of input1 can fetch data?

Comment: You need to define how context will look. Create your context using React.Context. Wrap everything in MainContent.js in Context.Provider with an initial value. Your MockTable.js will remain the same i.e. receiving callback function and updating state in the parent. In the UsecasePane component use, 'useContext' hook to get the value from context. For your ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54738889/6133559

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

Try to fetch your data in MainContent to centralize your datas and then dispatch. Use a callback (addData) to pass the new data to your parent

MainContent

```
const MainContent = () => {
    // get datas

    function addData(newData){
        setData([...data, newData])
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <CustomerTable />
        <AddMock addData={addData} />
        <MockTable data={data} />
      </div>
    );
};
```

AddMock

```
const AddMock = (props) => {
    // use props.addData(newData)
};
```

Comment: ``TabContent ``is not nested in ``MockTable``

Comment: So where are you rendering it ?

Comment: i have made some changes to the question. please take a look!

Comment: Ha you are trying to pass data from < MockTable /> to <AddMock /> ?

Comment: yes. in fact mocktable, addMock are child component of Maincontent

Comment: I think your workflow is not the best way, i'll edit my answer in some minutes

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which will return your array then you can pass an argument to that function which will be consumed in usecasepane component.

```
const panes = (arg) => {
// do something with arg...
return [
  {
    menuItem: "Usecase",
    render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}>{<UsecasePane arg={arg} />}</Tab.Pane>,
  }
];
}

const TabContent = () => (
  <Tab menu={{ secondary: true, pointing: true }} panes={ panes() } />
);
```