# Trigger a function in another component on click a button from a different component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to trigger a start function in a different `componentB` when I click the start button in `componentA`

**Note**: Both components are neither parent to child components

**Component A**

```
import React from "react"

function ComponentA(props) {        
  return (
    <div>
      <button>Start</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ComponentA;
```

**Component B**

```
import React from "react";

function ComponentB(props) {
  const [isStarted, setStarted] = React.useState(false);

  const start = () => setStarted(true);

  return <div>{isStarted ? "Starting..." : "Not Starting.."}</div>;
}

export default ComponentB;
```

Comment: use Redux or something similar i.e observables

Comment: What about context api?

Comment: They must be children of something even if it is just the window. `start()` and the associated state should be passed down from the parent of both.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do it is by creating a callback prop on ComponentA, changing the state of the parent component of ComponentA and passing it to ComponentB via a prop and capture that prop change with a useEffect.

Example:

**Parent**

```jsx
function Parent(){
  const [started, setStarted] = useState(false)

  return(
    <div>
      <ComponentA onClick={() => setStarted(true)}/>
      <ComponentB started={started}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**ComponentA**

```jsx
function ComponentA({onClick}){
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => onClick()}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**ComponentB**

```jsx
function ComponentB({started}) {
  const [isStarted, setStarted] = React.useState(started);

  useEffect(() => {
    setStarted(started)
  }, [started])

  return <div>{isStarted ? "Starting..." : "Not Starting.."}</div>;
}
```

Another way would be using useContext:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Honestly, I am a bit lazy to also include an example which is in my opinion worse. Here is an example that uses useContext that might be useful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54738889/7491597

Comment: Please how do I make use of the useContext?

Comment: I advise against using useContext everywhere in your app, especially when only one component needs information from another (which is in your case). useContext should really only be used if multiple components need the same application wide data. 
That being said you can find the documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Ok, please can you show a quick demo using my question above?

Comment: I'm just learning react/nextjs too and I was looking for the same solution, found this thread and did @BeFoRE 's 1st recommendation and it worked first try. I even passed "started" from componentB to a child component under componentB and it worked, so stoked!