# Using React Context with AsyncStorage using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

1. My goal is to use custom hooks created from Context to pass and modify stored values
2. The final goal is to use something like `useFeedContext()` to get or modify the context values
3. What I am actually getting is either the functions that I call are undefined or some other problem ( I tried multiple approaches)

I tried following this video [basics of react context](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LrDIWkK_Bc) in conjunction with this thread [How to change Context value while using React Hook of useContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54738681/how-to-change-context-value-while-using-react-hook-of-usecontext) but I am clearly getting something wrong.

Here is what I tried :

return part of App.js

```
    <FeedProvider mf={/* what do i put here  */}>
      <Navigation>
        <HomeScreen />
        <ParsedFeed />
        <FavScreen />
      </Navigation>
    </FeedProvider>
```

Main provider logic

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, useCallback } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const FeedContext = React.createContext();

const defaultFeed = [];


const getData = async (keyName) => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(keyName);
    return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
const storeData = async (value, keyName) => {
  console.log(value, keyName);
  try {
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(keyName, jsonValue);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

export const FeedProvider = ({ children, mf }) => {
  const [mainFeed, setMainFeed] = useState(mf || defaultFeed);
  const [feedLoaded, setFeedLoaded] = useState(false);

  let load = async () => {
    let temp = await AsyncStorage.getItem("mainUserFeed");
    temp != null
      ? getData("mainUserFeed").then((loadedFeed) => setMainFeed(loadedFeed))
      : setMainFeed(defaultFeed);
    setFeedLoaded(true);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    load();
  }, []);

  useCallback(async () => {
    if (!feedLoaded) {
      return await load();
    }
  }, [mainFeed]);

  const setFeed = (obj) => {
    setMainFeed(obj);
    storeData(mainFeed, "mainUserFeed");
  };

  return (
    <FeedContext.Provider value={{ getFeed: mainFeed, setFeed }}>
      {children}
    </FeedContext.Provider>
  );
};

//export const FeedConsumer = FeedContext.Consumer;

export default FeedContext;
```

The custom hook

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import FeedContext from "./feedProviderContext";

export default function useFeedContext() {
  const context = useContext(FeedContext);

  return context;
}
```

What I would hope for is the ability to call the `useFeedContext` hook anywhere in the app after import like:

```
let myhook = useFeedContext() 

console.log(myhook.getFeed) /// returns the context of the mainFeed from the provider
myhook.setFeed([{test:1},{test:2}]) /// would update the mainFeed from the provider so that mainFeed  is set to the passed array with two objects.
```

I hope this all makes sense, I have spend way longer that I am comfortable to admit so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep using your `useFeedContext` function, I suggest to move it into the your 'Provider Logic' or I'd call it as 'FeedContext.tsx'

**FeedContext.tsx**

```
const FeedContext = createContext({});
export const useFeedContext = () => {
  return useContext(FeedContext);
}

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [mainFeed, setMainFeed] = useState(mf || defaultFeed);
  ...
  return (
    <FeedContext.Provider value={{mainFeed, setMainFeed}}>
      {children}
    </FeedContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**YourScreen.tsx**

```
const YourScreen = () => {
  const {mainFeed, setMainFeed} = useFeedContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    // You have to wait until mainFeed is defined, because it's asynchronous.
    if (!mainFeed || !mainFeed.length) {
      return;
    }

    // Do something here
    ...
  }, [mainFeed]);

  ...
  return (
    ...
  );
};

export default YourScreen;
```

Comment: thank you so much ! I thought that the loop of useEffect and useCallback will be enough for the mainFeed to be loaded and therefore used in other screens. :D